# How to find the number of pointers in an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Is there any way to find out the length/number of pointers in an array of pointers?

i.e.

```
class Notifications {   
    iMessage **messages;
public:
    Notifications();
    Notifications(const Notifications&);
    Notifications& operator=(const Notifications&);
    Notifications(Notifications&&);
    Notifications&& operator=(Notifications&&);
    ~Notifications();
    void operator+=(const w5::iMessage&);
    void display(std::ostream&) const;

}
```

How would I be able to find the number of pointers within the array?

Comment: simple plain array wont tell you that

Comment: The address of the iMessage object are held in an array of pointers so iMessage** messages

Comment: There is not a single array in your code.

Comment: You would store the number in a variable, or use a terminating sentinel like C strings do, or actually use an array. `iMessage* messages[25];`: 25 pointers.

Comment: @AliKazmi Getting the number of elements in a "simple plain array" is fine. The problem is there isn't one here.

Comment: Use vectors and I bet many problems will disappear

Comment: You tagged this c++, so `std::vector` will help you, as well as solving/preventing a lot of problems that might occur...

Comment: I am unfortunately not allowed to use vectors

Comment: you can use new array container in C++ 11?

Comment: You code contains move-constr./-assignment but vectors are not allowed? This makes me sad.

Comment: @karsius not allowed to use `std::vector` ? your teacher shouldn't teach. The only exercice where it would make sense not forbid the use of `vector`would be the implementation of `vector`...
If this isn't an exercice and it is actually a policy, well this isn't even funny..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options, in order of increasing goodness:

Make the last one null and all the other ones non-null. This is the only solution which requires something of your data, think of it as a c-style string except with pointers instead of `char`s.

```
for (iMessage** msg  = messages; *msg; ++msg) { ... }
```

Store the size along with your messages:

```
iMessage **messages;
const size_t size;

for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    iMessage* msg = messages[i];
    // ...
}
```

Use a container specially designed to store arbitrary amounts of stuff in contiguous memory:

```
std::vector<iMessage*> messages;

for (iMessage* msg : messages) { 
    // ...
}
```

That's basically it, unless you know the size of `messages` up front and it's a compile-time constant, in which case one of:

```
iMessage* messages[100];
std::array<iMessage*, 100> messages;
```

gives you the size right in the type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do it. Some compilers have functions, to return the size of the allocated block, e.g. _msize in Visual Studio. If you divide that by the size of your pointers, you will get the number of elements in your "array".

But apart from being non-Standard, this only works, if the "array" has been allocated dynamically and the caller intends to use the whole block for the array - which is not always the case: Some libraries build own allocation functions on top of the standard ones. They allocate big blocks and then distribute that block further internally.

The correct way to do this (rather than guessing the size from the pointer) would be to let the code that created the array pass the size on to you and to store it along with the pointer. Alternatively, you can use C++ classes that do this for you (and maybe bounds checking in addition to that).